# jquery if statement, when dates don't match show 'default'

Tags: jquery

I have a json file like this:

```
{
  "video": {
    "default" : {
      "url": "http://showmms.rd.llnwd.net/d4/u/video/mezzanine/mov/1002742_1_0_trl02.mov",
      "imgSm": "http://www.sho.com/assets/vendor/sxsw/img/iphone-video.png",
      "imgLg": "http://www.sho.com/assets/vendor/sxsw/img/video-img.jpg",
      "imgTitle": "http://www.sho.com/assets/vendor/sxsw/img/video-title.jpg"
    },
    "mar8" : {
      "url": "http://showmms.rd.llnwd.net/d4/u/video/mezzanine/mov/1002742_1_0_trl02.mov",
      "imgSm": "http://www.sho.com/assets/vendor/sxsw/img/promos/SXSW2013_VOD_Banners_Dexter_Small_320x41.png",
      "imgLg": "http://www.sho.com/assets/vendor/sxsw/img/promos/SXSW2013_VOD_Banners_Dexter_Large_320x264.png",
      "imgTitle": "http://www.sho.com/assets/vendor/sxsw/img/video-title.jpg"
    },
    "mar9" : {
      "url": "http://showmms.rd.llnwd.net/d4/u/video/mezzanine/mov/1002742_1_0_trl02.mov",
      "imgSm": "http://www.sho.com/assets/vendor/sxsw/img/iphone-video.png",
      "imgLg": "http://www.sho.com/assets/vendor/sxsw/img/video-img.jpg",
      "imgTitle": "http://www.sho.com/assets/vendor/sxsw/img/video-title.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

}

so depending on the date it should display the proper image and url. But if it does not match the date, it should use "default", my jquery is not working but I'm not sure why:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var promo = 'mar' + dd;

var imgLg = data.video[promo].imgLg;
var imgSm = data.video[promo].imgSm;
var url = data.video[promo].url;

promo = data.video[promo] ? promo : 'default';

$("img.video-lg").attr("src",imgLg);
$("img.video-sm").attr("src",imgSm);    
$("a.play-btn").attr("href",url);
```

It works if the dates match but if not, it does not pull in the 'default'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var promo = 'mar' + dd;

if(data.video[promo] === undefined)
  promo = 'default';

var imgLg = data.video[promo].imgLg;
var imgSm = data.video[promo].imgSm;
var url = data.video[promo].url;

$("img.video-lg").attr("src",imgLg);
$("img.video-sm").attr("src",imgSm);    
$("a.play-btn").attr("href",url);
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably the dd will display for example 09 and not only 9 like you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to debug your code, the VAR dd will return the DAY only. You have to format the date first.